# Understanding 対してある vs. 対している vs. 対する

Tags: てある

I recently came across:

> 自分が相手にものを与える。また、**相手に対してある**行為をしたり、加えたりする。

For context, this is from a Japanese dictionary for the word 呉れる.

**Question:** Why is 対する being used in its ~てある form, as opposed to its 対する or 対している forms?

I know that ~てある is used to express a state that exists as the result of a deliberate action. For example: "ドアが閉めてある" means "the door has been closed (by someone, intentionally)". But that doesn't seem to be what's going on here?

Comment: It's 相手に対して、ある行為を〜

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This case I believe you want to parse it as [に対して](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%AB%E5%AF%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6) instead of 対してある since you have the に coming after 相手.

This would then indicate ある行為をしたり、加えたりする are regarding / in the context of whoever the 相手 (partner(s) / other party) is in the overall context.

So we get something roughly like:

> Oneself gives things to a partner. Also, regarding them, they do things like actions, get involved, and etc.

Comment: `get involved` <- 「加わる」ではなく「加える」(他動詞)ですけど？「相手に ある行為をしたり(do a certain action toward the other person)、相手に ある行為**を加え**たりする」ってことです。（「人に危害を加える」とかいうときの「加える」です）

Comment: @Chocolate そうです。「加えた」として「加えたりする」だと思いました。[加える](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%8A%A0%E3%81%88%E3%81%9F)の3目の意味です。でも、僕の翻訳がちょっと変かもしれません。質問が全部の文脈を付けなかったから「to include; to count in; to let join -> get involved with X -> get involved」だと思って加えた何を省きました。でも、僕も同じ考えです。「相手に対して」が「相手にある行為を○○」になるはずだと「加えたりする」の意味が「to inflict; to deal; to give」です。英語で「do things like actions, inflict things, or etc to the partner / other party」のようになります。1/2

Comment: Because my Japanese is certainly not the best. English version: Yep, I thought 加えたりする was 加えた. [加える](https://jisho.org/search/加えた)'s 3rd meaning. But my translation might be a little weird. Since the entire context was not included with the question, I was thinking "to include; to count in; to let join -> get involved with X -> get involved" and what was joined in on was omitted. But I agree. If 相手に対して should become 相手にある行為を○○ then 加えたりする means "to inflict; to deal; to give". And it becomes similar to "do things like actions, inflict things, or etc to the partner / other party" in English. 2/2

Answer (score 1):

The "ある" goes with "行為," meaning "a certain (action)."